# Converting a text string value from a spinner into an integer for mathematical manipulation in android

Tags: android, spinner, arrays

I have developed part of an application which contains a number of spinners to choose various options. I have created the spinners the following way:

```
Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String rowvalue =  null;

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
 R.array.chpugsp1_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
new     OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

rowvalue = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
}
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
});
```

My array (chpugsp1_array) is in the strings.xml file as:

```
<string name="chpugsp1"></string>
<string-array name="chpugsp1_array">
    <item>less than 34</item>
    <item>34-50</item>
    <item>greater than 50</item>
</string-array>
```

I am trying to convert the 3 different string arrays into different numerical values so that i can use them in a mathematical equation. For example, if "less than 34" is chosen, i want it to be equal to the value of 1 and saved as a variable (say variable1) that can be used later. I don't know how to turn each selection into a value.

I would also prefer the variable to be used in a different activity, is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say use what you already have.
Your `onItemSelected` method gives a value of `position`. This points to which item in the list was clicked.
Considering your list is static, the same position will always have the same value.

Due to this, you could use the position to assign a variable a certain value depending on your choice.

Try something like this.

```
private int yourInt;

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {

        rowvalue = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        switch (pos) {

        case 0:
            yourInt = 1; // First option picked
            break;

        case 1:
            yourInt = 2; // Second option
            break;

        case 2:
            yourInt = 3; // Third option
            break;

        }

    }
```

By using `Intents` with extra values you could then transfer this value to other `Activities`.
More info about that can be found [on this site](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents)

Comment: Ok before I try to put the integer into another activity, how can i test it out that it has acutally stored the yourInt as the correct value. I keep trying to put something like xxxx.setText("" + yourInt) but its not working.

Comment: Could you post the code where you try and set the text? You might be trying to set it in the wrong location.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the spinner index and store it in a `SharedPreference` :

```
int index =spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

editor.putInt("SpinnerValue", index);
editor.commit();
```